# Cocoapods unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, cocoapods

I am developing a private library.

This library is used accross multiple projects, so I am using a configs.plist in the projects that I am using this library to configure somethings.

The thing is that I would like to be able to execute an unit test in the projects that are using this library to be sure that the configs.plist has the minimal configuration required.

I've created a XCTestCase inside one of the projects that are using this library, but if I do it in this way I will need to copy this test to every other project using this library.

Is there anyway to add tests cases inside a cocoapods library that can be execute in any project that includes that pod?

Answer (score 0):

One pattern I've seen often is to create an "example" project that is checked in alongside the library code. For instance, check out how [Unbox](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox) does it.

The example project can exercise the functionality of the library in a minimal but complete fashion with unit tests. This structure makes it more natural to add and update tests at the same time as changes are made to the library.

In your case, you can have the example project load a series of `.plist` files that represent full coverage of the library's feature set. This way, you can be confident that any usage of the library in your app projects will behave correctly, but you don't have to maintain a separate test suite  within each app.